# How to batch delete mp4 files in a same folder right after zip one of them in linux?

Tags: linux, bash, command-line

My linux space has only 100M left, I have 100 mp4 files, each one is 90M size in same folder. I want to zip them into one .zip file. When I just use `zip -9 files.zip *.mp4`, it'll error because lack of space.

I tried the bash script below:

```
for f in $(ls *.mp4); do
    zip files.zip $f
rm -f $f
done
```

But it said:

```
zip error: Nothing to do! (/var/www/test/files.zip)
    zip warning: name not matched: myvideoname
```

Ok, I work out myself, This work:

```
tar -cvf files.tar *.mp4 --remove-files
```

Comment: Here's a quarter - buy a new hard drive :)

Comment: MP3s don't compress well. Take that quarter.

Comment: @FoggyDay Oh, please, that's absolutely not a solution

Comment: @Phoenix: And how much disk space did you recover, out of curiosity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works on my side:

```
#!/bin/bash
for f in *.mp4; do
    zip files.zip "$f"
done
```

Comment: so replace `$(ls *.mp4)` by `*.mp4`. The problem with `for f in $(ls *.mp4)` is that `for` loops in an array of strings where the space is the separator (the `$(ls *.mp4)` adds elements of ls separated by space), whereas in `for f in *.mp4` it loops over filenames, that can include spaces.

Comment: save it into `pack` filename and run, result `pack: line 5: syntax error: unexpected end of file`

Comment: what system are you using? I have bash4, and it works as it is.

Comment: Sorry, my typo when wrote the code... Yes, should be done, corrected it :)